# What effect does RSACryptoServiceProvider.KeySize size have?

Tags: powershell, encryption, rsa

I have a byte array of size 42.

I am encrypting this using an `RSACryptoServiceProvider` object:

```
$keySize = 16384
$rsaProvider = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider($keySize)
```

Do you need a cray super computer to decrypt using a key size that big?

Is there any benefit to using `$keySize = 2048` rather than 16384 in terms of memory etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a higher key size results in larger primes and modulus which makes it harder to factorize the modulus to get the primes out of it to then reveal the private key.

RSA is based on modular arithmetic. A higher key size also means that operations exponentiations on larger numbers must be performed. Key generation and decryption will be much slower. Encryption will be a little slower.

2048 is the minimal recommendation today. You might want to use 4096, but 16384 is almost certainly too much for your use case. But this depends on the attack model and the capabilities of the attacker.

Comment: how will using 16384 affect performance? I tested encrypting a small .txt file and it didn't make any difference using 16384  or 2048. If the file is significantly large, would it then make a noticeable difference if I used 2048 instead of 16384?

Comment: RSA only works for data roughly up to the size of the modulus. Everything above that and you will need [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem). Calculations on key sizes of 16384 should be much slower than on keys of size 2048 bit. If this is not the case then there is probably something wrong with the way you measure this. You should make the benchmarks yourself and use those numbers to arrive at useful balance between time and security, but as I said. You probably don't need keys higher than 8192.